# Missing return error

Tags: java, methods, return

```
/**
 * Read a positive integer and return its value
 * @param the prompt to be shown to the user
 */
public static int readPositiveInteger(String prompt)
{
    System.out.println (prompt);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    boolean positive = false;

    if (scan.hasNextInt() && positive == false)
    {
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        if (input > 0)
        {
            positive = true;
            {
                return input;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ("Bad input enter an integer.");
            positive = false;
            scan.nextLine();
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.println ("Bad input enter an integer.");
        positive = false;
        scan.nextLine();
    }



}
```

}

I'm trying to make it so the user can't insert 0 or a negative number. However I don't think my logic is correct as I'm getting a missing return error. Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: you have to return some thing , if control passes in to a loop where return statement is missing the error you mentioned will come , apply return statement wherever needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` should be a `while`:

```
while (scan.hasNextInt() && positive == false)
{
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    if (input > 0)
    {
        positive = true;
        {
            return input;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("Bad input enter an integer.");
        positive = false;
        scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Really, there's no need of keeping the `positive` boolean, since the moment it passes

```
if (input > 0)
```

it immediately returns, without any further checks on the boolean.

Answer (score 3):

Your method signature is as follows:

```
public static int readPositiveInteger(String prompt)
```

However, you never return an integer. You have two choices:

- Add something like `return 0;` to the end of your method
- Change `static int` to `static void`.

The first is the better option, I think, since you want to return the integer that was read. If none is read, you can tell the program a `0` was there.

The best option, though, is to modify your `if` statement to use a `while` loop, and return something only when the user has inputted something.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others here, your outer if statement should be a while loop:

```
while (scan.hasNextInt() && positive == false)
{
    ...
}
```

Also, you've only one return statement written in an if statement. If simply converting the above mentioned if statement to a while loop doesn't help, try `return 0` after your while loop.

The java compiler (and others as well) doesn't understand the semantics of code. It can only check for a correct syntax. So, in your case, it might be concerned that the return command might never be reached. A `return 0` at the end of your function would solve that (despite that `return 0` will never be reached).

Answer (score 3):

```
   public static int readPositiveInteger(String prompt)
     {
System.out.println (prompt);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an integer");
boolean positive = false;
int input;
if (scan.hasNextInt() && positive == false)
{
    input = scan.nextInt();
    if (input > 0)
    {
        positive = true;
        {
            return input;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("Bad input enter an integer.");
        positive = false;
        scan.nextLine();
    }
}

else 
{
    System.out.println ("Bad input enter an integer.");
    positive = false;
    scan.nextLine();
}
return input;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

All paths of your method should return something since you define it as

```
public static int readPositiveInteger(String prompt)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are expecting your code to be in a while loop or something?
As it stands it can "run off the bottom" - and like the error says, there is no return (which is required).

Answer (score 2):

You need a while loop. In pseudo code:

```
While true (ie loop forever)
   Ask for input
   If input ok return it
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a return statement in the else block otherwise your code wont compile

your method expects a return statement in the else block

```
 else
        {
            System.out.println ("Bad input enter an integer.");
            positive = false;
            scan.nextLine();
            return 0;//your missing return statement

        }
    }
```

Comment: this would return 0 if the first argument isn't positive and exit the function. That might not be what the questioneer wants.

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is add `return input;` in the end of the method that is

```
public static int readPositiveInteger(String prompt) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        boolean positive = false;

        if (scan.hasNextInt() && positive == false) {
            int input = scan.nextInt();
            if (input > 0) {
                positive = true;
                {
                    return input;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Bad input enter an integer.");
                positive = false;
                scan.nextLine();
            }
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Bad input enter an integer.");
            positive = false;
            scan.nextLine();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This function will work perfectly for you

```
public static int readPositiveInteger(String prompt) {
        System.out.println(prompt);     
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean positive = false;
        int input = 0;

        while (input <= 0) {
            System.out.println("please enter a number greater then 0");
            input = scan.nextInt();
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int readPositiveInteger() 
{
return int_type;
}
```

has the return type as int so you should return the integer values in function.